# How to pass argument values containing non-ascii characters to CLI apps?

Tags: macos, character-encoding, command-line-interface, osx-yosemite

I'm unable to correctly pass UTF-8 string values as arguments to command line apps.

Approaches I've tried:

- pass the value between double quotes: "café"
- pass with single quotes: 'café'
- use the char code: 'caf\233'
- use a $ sign before the string: $'café'

I'm using Mac OS 10.10, iTerm and my current locale outputs:

```
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: How are you calling your program? What program are you calling and how does it read its arguments? I can't reproduce this: `touch café && ls café && cat café && rm café` works fine.

Comment: @RobNapier, I'm using id3tag and/or id3tool.

Both of them have the same issue.

`id3tag out.mp3 --song="Café"`

`id3tool out.mp3 --set-title="Café"`

Comment: What do you mean by "have the same issue?" What is the actual symptom?

Comment: @RobNapier, this two apps serve the purpose of id3 tag manipulation of mp3 files.

Setting any tag with a string containing non-ascii characters results in corrupted text, not the intended text with accents and/or special characters. **Café** turns into **CafÃ©**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is doubtful this has anything to do with the shell. I would make sure that your tools (both the writer tools and whatever you're reading with) correctly deal with UTF-8 at all. I would most suspect that whatever you're reading your tags with is interpreting and printing this as Latin-1. You should look inside the file with a hex editor and look for the tag. I'm betting it will be correct (C3 82, which is é in UTF-8, and Ã© in Latin-1). Your output tool is probably the problem, not the writer (and definitely not the shell).

If your reading tool demands Latin-1, then you need to encode é as E9. The `iconv` tool can be useful in making those conversions for scripts.

Comment: It seems to be a coincidence that both writing apps aren't dealing with UTF-8.

Comment: Tests with 3 distinct methods for reading the tags results consistently the same error. Here I discard the hypothesis of reading error. One of the methods was using an IDE which succesfully could write the faulting content.

I've written a simple Node JS app to test the hypothesis of misinterpretation of the arguments and all characters were succesfully interpreted.

Therefore I think we can blame both apps mishandling of UTF-8 and not the shell.